# Erasing an object in a vector of vector issue

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

I'm trying to "erase" an element from a vector that is itself contained in another vector. However, either I forgot how to do this, I  missed the point, or there's a huge oversight. It always erases the very first element in the vector, whatever I try.

```
void release_docking() {

    int loop_R = (int)parent_cell->cells.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < loop_R; i++) {

        int loop_C = (int)parent_cell->cells[i].size();

        for (int j = 0; j < loop_C; j++) {

            if (parent_cell->cells[i][j] = this) {

                parent_cell->cells[i].erase(parent_cell->cells[i].begin() + j);

                if (parent_cell->cells[i].empty()) {
                    parent_cell->cells.erase(parent_cell->cells.begin() + i);
                }

                parent_cell = nullptr;
                is.docked = false;
                resize_cells(root_cell);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And `parent_cell->cells[i][j] = this` does not seem right to me... Do you mean `==`?

Comment: Unrelated: Why are you casting to `int` everywhere? Declare your variables as `std::size_t` or `auto` and get rid of the casting.

Comment: When you erase the `i` element or `j` element, you must also decrement that value `i`/`j`, otherwise your loop will skip the elements right after them.

Example : your vector is {5, 6, 7, 8}, i=1 (pointing at 6), if you erase the element at i and then let the loop continue to the next cycle, the next iteration looks like {5, 7, 8}, i=2 (pointing at 8, thus skipping 7)

Comment: Also, it is dangerous to copy the size of each vector into a constant variable, as you are adjusting the size one the run...

Comment: thanks to everyone, I'm all new to this, it is very appreciated!!

Comment: Some people prefer to write comparisons as `const == var` instead of `var == const` to avoid such unfortunate mistakes.

Comment: @Evg enter the world of Yoda !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
if (parent_cell->cells[i][j] = this) {
```

will assign `this` to `parent_cell->cells[i][j]` and evaluate to true.

After that it will be erased.

That should be `==` not `=`.

Recent compilers should warn you about this. Make sure that warnings are turned on.

Comment: omg, it's been hours of struggle, I didn't even notice my mistake !! Thanks a lot !!!